# Ruby regex to match decimal number with percentage and only decimal numbers

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

The ruby  regex expression (`\d*[,]?\d*[.]\d+`) matches both 45.00 and 45.00%. How to tune this regex that it matches only 45.00 and 45.00%

Comment: Hmm... I hope that in your last sentence you meant *only 45.00 and NOT 45.00%*, because otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: You saw @AlinPurcaru's comment, but neither replied nor clarified your question. Not good. Please clarify with an edit. It would be helpful to provide a few examples of what you want and don't want to extract from a string.

Comment: After reading the comment you left on my answer, clarifying your question. I've deleted my answer. As others may wish to see the comment, it was as follows: "For example, in my documents it has 45.00 , 45.00(Any no of spaces)%,45,000.00(Any no of spaces)$ and others like 34,999.00 , 56.78.I want to extract only decimal such as (98.05, 9,990.00) and not (98.56 %, 87.90$)". btw, rather than leaving a comment, you should edit your question and add the information there.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a negative lookahead and make the decimal matching possessive:

```
\d*[,]?\d*[.]\d++(?!%)
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/yNAk3JCK4H)

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks for the correction! I remembered it wrong that *possessive = greedy* because I associated this with *greedy algorithms*, where you don't go into backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for either.  You can try this, it will match both
45.00 and 45.00%

```
(\d*[,]?\d*\.\d+[%]?)
```

But the best way to test regex's is with [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

You can enter several lines of test data and then check that your regex matches what you expect

Answer (score 0):

I would clean that up to:

```
\d[\d,.]*+(?!%)
```

Comment: You introduced some false positives with the cleanup: `0,,0,`

Comment: @Alin and I removed some false negatives: 1,000,000 :)